# Aldebaran NAO Cross-Compilation. I can´t generate rostoolchain files

Tags: cross-compiling, cross-compilation, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:

I am following this tutorial for Nao robot and cross compilation ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling )

After installation of ROS-Base electric from source, no rostolchain file appears into my installation dir subfolders. I have followed procedure in this link ( electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source ) modified like that:

rosinstall $TARGETDIR/ros/electric "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=ros-base&overlay=no"

I could not follow step 4 in Cross-Compiling tutorial. I see that maybe the procedure for installing ros electric has changed and finally in   ´´/media/external/ros/electric¨ only appear: common_rosdeps  ros  ros_comm  setup.bash  setup.sh  setup.zsh

Maybe I have to build a toolchain by using eros?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43003/aldebaran-nao-cross-compilation.-i-can%C2%B4t-generate-rostoolchain-files./) by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just past the contents of the box in the wiki page into your terminal. It will generate a rostoolchain.cmake file

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0